# Group Delay of a GLP

Tags: matlab, group-delay

I am trying to understand what is the Group delay from a given figure.
I was given an assignment with the following figure:
[image]

and was asked the following:
"what is the group delay (in the passband of the filter) and how is it related to the
number of FIR coefficients?"

Comment: It’s well documented here and elsewhere what group delay is (the negative derivative of phase with respect to frequency). Did you know that and does anything about that confuse you?

Comment: i"m well aware of the definition of a group delay, nevertheless,
i m having trouble figuring the group delay from the attached figure

Comment: Ok very good- so your figure is showing you phase versus frequency in the middle plot. Please clarify your issue or confusion in not being able to take the derivative of that middle plot (negative derivative of phase with respect to frequency) and hopefully I can help clear that up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine group delay from the frequency response of FIR filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73580/determine-group-delay-from-the-frequency-response-of-fir-filter)

Comment: Do you know what "phase unwrapping" is ?

Comment: thanks Dan, much appreciated!